# CRON NodeJs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cron

- Hello, I have a little problem, I want display every user's email from database Mongo in console.log();.
- When I start my CRON I have result UNDEFINED.
- Thanks for your answer

> my code

```
var User = require('./models/user');

var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('0-59 0-59 0-23 * * 0-6', function(req, res) {


    User.find(function(err, user) {
        console.log("CRON is started !" + user.email)
    });

}, function () {
    /* This function is executed when the job stops */
    console.log("CRON is stoped !")
},
true /* Start the job right now */
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your are using Mongoose for the MongoDB related stuff and you defined your own User model. The result from MongoDb will be an array of objects so `user.email` is not possible. You have to iterate over all returned objects in the array.

Try using:

```
// get all the users
User.find({}, function(err, users) {

  // optional but i would recommend to use it so that you can see possible errors with your query
  if (err) throw err;

  // iterate over all users of all the users
  users.forEach(function(user) {
    console.log("CRON is started !" + user.email);
  });
});
```

Comment: perfect :) can your mark the answer as correct so further developer can fix it too?