# Sending an email when user has not logged-in to app in a while

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need some suggestions on how to go about implementing sending an email to a user when they haven't been logged in to an app in say 3 days (in javascript). Basically, notifying a user based on their `lastLoggedIn` status which i'd store in the Database. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737708/how-to-run-cron-job-with-firebase

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cloud Scheduler to create a job with a `pubsub` Cloud Function as target, using the same `topic`.

Use the frequency option to set the 3 days.

**Edit**:

Or you can use this new feature:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
  return null;
});
```

Which is basically the same:

> When you deploy a scheduled function, the related scheduler job and
>   pub/sub topic are created automatically. The Firebase CLI echoes the
>   topic name, and you can view the job and topic in the GCP Console.

Answer (score 1):

You should write a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) task for your database.

Like, some code that will run everyday @10.00 AM to check whether user's lastLoggedIn is greater that 3 days. Later on you can notify those pooled users.

Check this [nodejs mongodb cron thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47780455/cron-nodejs-mongodb) that will give you an opinion.
Hope it helps!